# A react(typescript) project that uses Near api js works in dev but not preview mode

Tags: typescript, vite, near-api-js

Am using a react project(typescript) with vite, the project interacts with a deployed sample donations smart contract.

The project works as expected in dev mode but once built and deployed I encounter the following error in the console.

[image]

I have tried altering the near API js dependency to a different version, but there is still an error.
The repository to the project that am using is [here](https://github.com/Arthur-Kamau/near-donations-ui)

I have also tried renaming the default component names to custom component names.

when I comment out the near API js imports and code it works fine.

how do I resolve the error ?